# Azure search and twitter autocomplete with prefetch

Tags: c#, azure, typeahead, azure-cognitive-search

I have integrated azure [search suggestions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.search.documentoperationsextensions.suggestasync.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentOperationsExtensions.SuggestAsync(Microsoft.Azure.Search.IDocumentOperations,System.String,System.String,Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SuggestParameters)) and twitter typeahead on a site of mine and thats working fine. What I want to do though,which isnt working,is use the typeahead prefetch functionality (so that the suggestions are cached on the client side). I cant seem to do a wildcard 'suggestion' so that i can pull the data back (less than 100items and small in size). Anyone know how to do this?I have tried passing in the '*' character but that returns nothings. Thoughts?